# How "Technical Project" in moodle Works?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

After Installation of this plug-in(Technical Project) When I goes to the technical Project setting from (site administration >> plug-ins >> activity modules >> technical project) I am getting this page.
My question is that how can i test all of its features as I have installed it in my localhost moodle. 
[technical Project view after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gjmx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a core Moodle module, its a custom plugin. So there isn't any official documentation from Moodle. But you can find more details here :

https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_techproject

There is documentation here

https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/mod/techproject/view